# Problem with Refreshing entire excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to refresh a entire excel workbook using Application.CalculateFull function. However, I found that, the sheet does not get not updated ALL the time (sometimes it do).
A random number of functions only get updated at sometimes. I'm using excel 2007, please tell me what's going on with Application.CalculateFull function.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this line instead?

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```